# Generate linkin sequential order rather then random order

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate the following links in sequential order, then restart at top of list, but do not to randomize the links

```
 <script>
 var randomlinks=new Array()

 randomlinks[0]="http://java.com"
 randomlinks[1]="http://javascriptkit.com"
 randomlinks[2]="http://dynamicdrive.com"
 randomlinks[3]="http://cnn.com"
 randomlinks[4]="http://www.geocities.com"

 function randomlink(){
 window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
 }
 //-->
 </script>
```

Comment: Then why are you using `Math.random()` when picking an array element?

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = ["http://java.com", "another url here", ...];
nextIndex = 0;
cycleLinks();

function cycleLinks()
{
    // get next link
    nextLink = links[nextIndex];
    nextIndex = nextIndex % links.length;

    // display link
    window.location = nextLink;

    // after a while, change the link
    // if you don't do that, the displayed webpage will probably disappear too fast
    setTimeout(cycleLinks, 1000);
}
```

Comment: i tried this but am getting cycleLinks undefined, how am i supposed to input my links var=["http://www.cnn",""], was not to sure

Comment: I fixed it. [Note that we can get in trouble for spoonfeeding here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204794/do-i-deserve-downvoting-for-answering-spoon-feeding-answers). Please show that you are also investing time and effort in this. (PS: This is probably the reason for why you were down-voted.)

Comment: well i was able to get both scripts to run, Domi, this script seem to open on its own,, i need it to open when i call for it cycleLinks().  If this is used by other users on different computers will it still just goto next link example if I open java.c**, will the next user on a another computer will open the following url

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies, and store the last link shared.

```
var randomlinks=new Array();
    randomlinks[0]="http://java.com"
    randomlinks[1]="http://javascriptkit.com"
    randomlinks[2]="http://dynamicdrive.com"
    randomlinks[3]="http://cnn.com"
    randomlinks[4]="http://www.geocities.com"

 function randomlink(){
    var itemsCount = randomlinks.length;
    var newSuggest = getCookie("lastlink");

    if(typeof newSuggest !== "undefined"){
        newSuggest = parseInt(newSuggest);
        if((newSuggest+1)<itemsCount){
            newSuggest++;
        }else{
            newSuggest=0;
        }
        setCookie("lastlink",newSuggest,30);
        window.location = randomlinks[newSuggest];

    }else{
        setCookie("lastlink",0,30);
    }
 }



function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(cookie) {
    return document.cookie.split(';').reduce(function(prev, c) {
        var arr = c.split('=');
        return (arr[0].trim() === cookie) ? arr[1] : prev;
    }, undefined);
}
```

Comment: This worked great but will it always start at same link on everyones computer, was hoping it just remove it until all links have been used then refresh loop

Comment: then use Math.rand and not to use same links store the used id's in cookie

Comment: are you saying I can use math rand and cookies, and if so how do I write that line please